# Dynamodb GetBatchItem vs query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Currently I use table.query to get items by matching partition key and sorted by sorting key. Now the new requirement is to handle batch query - a couple of hundred partition keys match and hopefully still sorted by sorting key in each partition key result. I find GetBatchItem that can handle up to 100 items per one query, but look like no sorting. Is one item here one row in DDB or all rows in one partition key?
From performance(query speed) and price perspective which one should I use? And do i have to do sorting for  the result by myself if I use GetBatchItem? Ideally I like a solution of fast, cost effective and result sorted by sorting key in each partition key, but the first two are top priority and I can do sorting if I have to. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Query()` is cheaper...

`BatchGetItem()` runs as individual `GetItem()` each costing 0.5 RCU (assuming your item is less than 4K and eventually consistent reads).

Lets say you're item is 512 Bytes, `Query()` can return 16 of them for 1 RCU whereas returning 16 via `BatchGetItem()` will cost 8 RCU.

Comment: Just a correction, 1RCU = 4K not 400K

Comment: thanks...I've updated the numbers...